# What kind of index to create for solr search?

Tags: search

I have got a solr instance up and running locally on my drupal 7 server.
I have added the server to the search config on my drupal site and now I'm trying to create the 'index' part of the search configuration.

As per this guide http://valuebound.com/resources/blog/installing-configuring-apache-solr-520-with-drupal-7-using-search-api-ubuntu-1404 I have gotten to the very end where I must set up the index for the files.

The guide says to select 'Node' from the drop-down list under 'Item type' but I don't see that option.  Is there another option I can select?

I am planning on indexing a bunch of 'rich' file types such as PDFs, DOCS, XLS as well as JSON and XML.

I am looking for help in setting up the search index for my solr server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The item dropdown says "Content" instead of "node". But "content" == "node" in this case.